# How to show only one ItemLabel in radchart telerik

Tags: silverlight-4.0, telerik, radchart

I'm using radchart,in the chart i'm able to show 4 series and in that one of the series is line as the value will be same for each x axis value.Now i want to hide the all ItemLabel except one ItemLabel i.e showing the item label at last x axis value,is there any way to show only one ItemLabel for the series.

[image: 1]:![Chart To single Item label]

FYI,
Series colored green to show the only one itemlabel at last is there any possiblity.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Posting this question in telerik they provided me the solution.

[Answer](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/general-discussions/how-to-show-only-one-itemlabel-in-line-series-in-radchart.aspx)